# ms-access: how do i insert a PDF onto a report?

Tags: ms-access

is it possible to insert a PDF onto an access report? how?

Comment: You might try experimenting with an unbound OLE control, but I couldn't get it to work with Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to embed an a PDF into a box on a ms-access report, say as an ActiveX object, or export Ms-Access to PDF?  If ActiveX, try this http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/sdk/activex/ but mileage can vary with ActiveX objects in MS-Office.

Comment: Not all ActiveX controls work in Access. I would avoid any ActiveX solution if possible, myself.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton.  100% correct. Last time I did Ms-Access work, the 3rd party COM+ and components really destabilized the the database when they did work.